# which server-software is recommended to run java-based webservices

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

i was wondering which server-software (tomcat, ...) is recommended to run a webservice written in java. are there actually any alternatives to tomcat?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each JavaEE server ([Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/), [JBoss](http://jboss.org/jbossas), etc) supports web-services. In fact, Tomcat does not provide out-of-the-box support for them.

I, personally, would go for Tomcat + a JAX-WS provider like [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

We generally work with Tomcat and JBoss, using Axis for the web service implementation. Works for us.